# Phonegap build fails for android because of the facebookconnect plugin

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

For the past couple of days we weren't able to build our app for android because of the Facebook connect plugin (it worked perfectly before). In the log there is an error:

"*BUILD FAILED
/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:597: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/project/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/cinema-FacebookLib/build.xml:46: sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through an env var*"

I know that [Facebook Connect](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect) plugin was deprecated and replaced by [phone gap-Facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) and when I setup my `config.xml` according to [Phone Gap Build Guide](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/pg-build/README.md) it still doesn't work.

We are using phone gap version 3.7.0.

I'm in the pickle because we need to update the app soon so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed by adding this line in the config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
```